# Finiteness character of a couple of series

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

While working on a probability problem I have found that the following series should be finite:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lbrace[\frac{1}{c}(1-q^i)-1]^m+1\right\rbrace
$$
(for $m$ an odd positive integer and $c$ a positive integer major or equal than two). And:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lbrace -[\frac{1}{c}(1-q^i)-1]^m+1\right\rbrace
$$
for $m$ an even positive integer and $c$ a positive integer major or equal than two.

Sadly, I've not been able to prove both formulae are finite.

Comment: I forgot to say that $0<q<1$.

Comment: That seems unlikely unless I have misunderstood.  If for example $c=2, m=1, q=\frac12$ then $\frac14 \le \frac1c\left(1-q^i\right) \le \frac12$ and $-\frac34 \le \left[\frac1c\left(1-q^i\right)-1\right]^m \le -\frac12$ so you are summing an infinite number of terms each at least $\frac14$.   There seems to be a similar issue with your second expression

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely right! I'll have a closer look at my computations.